# Error ubuntu server 18.04.4 "apt update" unable to update server repository

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management, updates, amazon-ec2

When I try to update Ubuntu Server 18.04.4, a repository returns an error and I am unable to update the server.

```
root# apt update

Err:1 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable InRelease                                                                                                                            
  Unknown error executing apt-key                                                                                                                                                                                                               
Err:3 http://ap-south-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Unknown error executing apt-key
Err:4 http://ap-south-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Unknown error executing apt-key
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable InRelease: Unknown error executing apt-key
E: The repository 'https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bionic-pgdg InRelease: Unknown error executing apt-key
E: The repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bionic-pgdg InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Have you confirmed the server has the most recent public signing keys for these repositories?

Comment: Is your server updated?  A fully-updated 18.04 or *bionic* server will report itself as 18.04.5, which was released (ISO) in 14 August 2020 (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/) though installed systems upgraded to it before that ISO release date.

Comment: @matigo yes I have checked the most recent public signing keys available in repositories, if have recent keys please share I can go with the same, please help me here. I have many servers here and I'm unable to update patches and repository here.
thanks

Comment: @guiverc my server is in 18.04.4 so I'm trying to update with ubuntu 18.04.5, but the repository is not updating and throwing error of GPG.not without "apt-update", How can update my servers ?
please help here
Thanks